# Opacity property doesn't give expected result in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So i've been trying for quite some time now to create the following effect on this screen i'm working on:

[image]

What i want to do is create a transparent effect using the gradient as a background, but i haven't been able to do that. I've tried to use the linear-gradient() function in css and then decreasing the opacity, but this was the result:

[image]

I also tried using a transparent svg with the same gradient, but that and trying the same svg but with decreased opacity also failed:

[image]

[image]

This is the code i've been using, both css and html:

```css
        .login-section {
    
        .card {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            box-shadow: 1px 3px 9px 3px rgba(142, 142, 142, 0.19);
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            min-height: 300px;
        }
    
        .gradient {
            background: url(../../../../assets/images/login.svg);
        }
    
        .login-form {
        }
    
        .logo {
            max-height: 100px;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <section class="login-section d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100 border-0">
        <div class="card-body row p-0 mx-0">
            <div class="col gradient d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start pb-4">
                   <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <h5 class="text-white">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col login-form py-4 px-5">
                <p color="#636363" class="d-flex justify-content-center">Seja bem-vindo</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                            placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone
                            else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use css gradient instead of background image. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

Comment: just an exxample on how you could use your gradient : https://jsfiddle.net/dwo6n8m4/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mask property
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image
Take in to consideration that this is an experimental property you can check the support [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20mask)

```css
picture{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  
}
picture::after{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<picture>
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg"/>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
.grad{
background: rgba(212,228,239,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(212,228,239,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(212,228,239,1) 0%, rgba(134,174,204,0.49) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e4ef', endColorstr='#86aecc', GradientType=1 );
}
```

Comment: please use `Ctrl+k` to show text as code and add explain

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ***Opacity*** css feature on the div that contains the image like this:

Notice that opacity affects the entire div so I would suggest creating a separate div for the "background properties" and then another for the content; this [Article](http://www.lets-develop.com/html5-html-css-css3-php-wordpress-jquery-javascript-photoshop-illustrator-flash-tutorial/css-css3-css-3-style-styling/set-background-opacity-css-not-affecting-inner-content-child-elements/) (***Look at the solution 4 on the article which is the most clean way to get that***) explains the process of exactly the same visual effects you need

```css
        .login-section {
    
        .card {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
            box-shadow: 1px 3px 9px 3px rgba(142, 142, 142, 0.19);
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            min-height: 300px;
        }
    
        .gradient {
            background: url(../../../../assets/images/login.svg);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    
        .login-form {
        }
    
        .logo {
            max-height: 100px;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <section class="login-section d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100 border-0">
        <div class="card-body row p-0 mx-0">
            <div class="col gradient d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start pb-4">
                   <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <h5 class="text-white">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col login-form py-4 px-5">
                <p color="#636363" class="d-flex justify-content-center">Seja bem-vindo</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                            placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone
                            else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```